# Post a public photo using the Facebook Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the Facebook Graph API to post a photo to a user's album.

The posting of the photo works and is created in the requested album but I have been unable to make the photo public.

The album is set to public and other photos in the album are available to logged out users. When the user gives permission to the app they also select that anything posted by the app is made public. Any ideas why this is happening?

Here is the code:

```
$ret_obj = $this->facebook->api('123123123/photos', 'POST', array(
    'source' => '@' . $photo,
    'message' => $message,
));
```

These are the permissions I'm asking for:

```
$url = $this->facebook->getLoginUrl( array(
    'scope' => 'photo_upload, user_photos, publish_stream'
));
```

Answer (score 2):

As per the [Reference docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/photos) (which did not contain this information, but I've since added) you need to supply an additional `privacy` parameter in your API call, which I believe looks like this (my PHP is not strong):

```
$privacy = array(
  'value'=> 'EVERYONE',
)

$ret_obj = $this->facebook->api('123123123/photos', 'POST', array(
                                 'source' => '@' . $photo,
                                 'message' => $message,
                                 'privacy' => $privacy
                                 )
                              );
```

Comment: Oh, and you should consider upgrading to our newer PHP SDK (4.0.0) which was launched yesterday: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/uploadphoto/4.0.0

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately adding this doesn't work. It's still not available for logged out users. As per the docs, if this isn't supplied, it defaults to the choice made by the user in the login dialog, which in this case was public.

Comment: What does the privacy indicator on the newly created photo say?

Comment: It says public. This is the photo url:
[link](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10151985533547493&set=a.10151985407987493.1073741846.707907492&type=3&theater)

Comment: Hmm, that is strange, I just tested using the `url` method of uploading and was able to successfully see the photo with a logged out browser. I recommend you [file a bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs) so that one of our support team can investigate this more deeply.

Comment: Thanks, I've filed a bug [here](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/637511952992329/).